# what is the @param in elasticsearch bulk load

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk-load

I am following the tutorial in
    https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/getting-started.html

I downloaded the sample json files and put it in
    /mydirectory/data/accounts.json

according to the documentation, you would type
    curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @accounts.json

Of course then you get an error
{
   "statusCode": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "message": "child \"uri\" fails because [\"uri\" must be a valid uri]",
   "validation": {
      "source": "query",
      "keys": [
         "uri"
      ]
   }
}

because I don't see anyway to indicate which directory I stored the json file. How do you get it to know where to find the search. I googled all around, and am amazed to not find the answer. How did everybody else figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the full path after the `@` character,  like this

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @/mydirectory/data/accounts.json
```

An alternative is to first run `cd /mydirectory/data` and then you can use

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @accounts.json
```

Comment: I did already try that. same result. {
   "statusCode": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "message": "child \"uri\" fails because [\"uri\" must be a valid uri]",
   "validation": {
      "source": "query",
      "keys": [
         "uri"
      ]
   }
} Maybe the problem is else where?

Comment: ok, I got it to work. I was doing this using kibana sense, and the post did not work there. I will accept your answer.